# google-services.json - changed package_name - do i need to create a new configuration file

Tags: android, google-play-services

My current environemnt already has a google-services.json file and everything works.  But now due to unforeseen circumstance i must rename the package of my project.  I have successfully renamed the package now. I also went into the google-services.json file and renamed the package name there as well. So now i am wondering do i need to go back onto the google developer site and create a new configuration file ?

Basically i am concerned that renaming the package namein google-services.json is not sufficient. i think that configuration is tied to the original package name. I am wondering when a developer renames the package name of a project is it necesaary to generate a new configuration file from [google developer site](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) ?

Here is the google-services.json file i originally generated and i'll show you how i changed the package name :

```
 {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "987654321",
    "project_id": "firebase-project_myapp"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:234567:android:1011212314151617",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.NewPackageName" //i updated package name
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "adlskfjsd;fjkalskdjfalk;sdfj"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Again is it sufficientn to to only update package_name in the json file or do i need to create all new projects for my app ?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I think we should create new app in firebase console and generare new json file

Comment: Yes, even I did the same, just wanted to confirm it before posting the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the package name in the google-services.json file will not work as it does not act as an update mechanism of any sort but merely a repository of data to be used during services instance establishment.

Yes, it is necessary to create a new configuration file by creating a new application or by deleting the current application in the console you can re-use the application name originally used. This is because each google services instance are generated specifically for a particular application tied to the package name with specific identifiers. So it is an absolute necessity to create a new application and use the google-services.json file from that application settings.

Comment: i agree after some research.

Comment: Thanks for this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by just renaming the package from the googleservices.json file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We need add an app in firebase-console inside the project with new package name and then download and replace that json in the project directory.

Worked for me!