# How to update the package name in existing flutter app which is using firebase and firebase functions in the project?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want change the package name in flutter, for the existing project which is using firebase and firebase cloud functions in the project.

According to this article,

[Click here for the article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901727)

**I have downloaded the new google-services.json file with new package name works fine.But is the right method to change the package name? for production apps**

**P.S: Suggest an edit if there's anything wrong with the question**

*Thanks for the help in advance :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple method to change package name in flutter, simply add [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) to your dependency and run the following command

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

where com.new.package.name is your new package name.

Comment: So, it is valid  to change the package name for the existing project?

Comment: yup, it is valid.

Comment: can i remove the dependency after changing the package name?

Comment: yes you can remove the dependency after you change the package name.